# Modulate a recorded sound into different effects in android?

Tags: android, audio-recording, audio

I'm going to make an app related to sound modulation , where i need to record a sound and after recording the sound i need to play it in different modulation or sound effects like **Reversing,Resampling,Pitchshifting,Robatization**  effect when I press the play button .Now I have the code to record a sound ,but don't know how to modulate the recorder  sound as the above effects.

I search the whole web but did not find any solution.how do i implement this effects?

Answer (score 1):

There are many apis which helps to accomplish this. For example-

Open SLES. AudioTrack.

Please have a look at [this](http://www.wiseandroid.com/post/2010/07/13/Intro-to-the-three-Android-Audio-APIs.aspx) page.

I think it may help you.